# Am I duplicating data in my API?

Tags: json, api

My **gradepoints** and **percents** objects hold the same values of grades with different keys. Please take a look at my json below and let me know if I'm doing it right. Is there a way to optimize this API?

I could provide the percents along with the **gradepoints** after a comma like **"a1": "10,90"** but this way I will need to split them up on client side JS, which I'm restraining from.

```
{
  "gradepoints": [
    {
      "a1": 10
    },
    {
      "a1": 10
    },
    {
      "c2": 5
    },
    {
      "e1": "eiop"
    },
    {
      "d": 4
    },
    {
      "b1": 8
    }
  ],
  "percents": [
    {
      "a1": 90
    },
    {
      "a1": 90
    },
    {
      "c2": 45
    },
    {
      "e1": "eiop"
    },
    {
      "d": 36
    },
    {
      "b1": 72
    }
  ],
  "gpa": 7.4,
  "overall": 70.3,
  "eiop": 2
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `a1` twice in each array?

Comment: that's normal for the simple functioning of my frontend, any student can get a same grade in 2 or more subjects.

Comment: What are `a1`, `c2`, etc.? I was guessing those were the names of the subjects.

Comment: Those are the grades, I wish I could also put together the subjects.

Comment: Currently I'm accepting comma separated list of grades in my rest api and splitting them on commas to make an array out of them. If I also accept x number subjects with grades, how would accept them in the url? Currently i'm doing this /grades/:g and then process the g thing.

Comment: The URL can contain an array of subjects in JSON notation, or as `subject[]=subj1&subject[]=subj2&...`

Comment: @Barmar so my url would be like /grades/subject[]=sub1&subject[]=2&grades[]=a1&grades[]=a2 wouldn't that be complex?

Comment: Most languages provide an easy way to parse that. E.g. if you use PHP, it will create an array `$_GET['subject']` with all the subjects, `$_GET['grades']` with all the grades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like this:

```
{
    grades: [
        {   name: "a1",
            gradepoint: 10,
            percent: 90
        },
        {   name: "a1",
            gradepoint: 10,
            percent: 90
        },
        {   name: "c2",
            gradepoint: 5,
            percent: 45
        },
        ...
    ],
    gpa: 7.4,
    overall: 70.3,
    eiop: 2
}
```

Related data should be kept together in an object.

If it weren't for the duplicate `a1` entries, I would probably make `grades` be an object, with the names as keys. But an object can't have duplicate keys, so it has to be put in the values.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I was looking for this design only. This is my first API design, I hope to learn more through SO. One thing i learn today "Related data should be kept together in an object." or group related data.